# Linux, Grub and Win 7 problem

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, grub

I have several problems, but here I will just focus on the current most important one.

I have Mint on an SSD that used to be in a laptop that had Win 7 installed on a separate SSD running as dual boot. The laptop broke and I used an old win 7 machine to try to boot into the Mint SSD. Unfortunately, the win SSD was still in it so grub got screwed.

Now I have a newer Win 7 machine that is used for music and video production. I thought I would be safe removing the Win 7 SSD from that machine and putting the Mint SSD in to try to fix grub. So I did and booted  from a grub rescue disk. Grub rescue did it's thing and told me it was fixed. So I rebooted and my old grub complete with my own background image came up on the screen. However, when booting into Mint it would get so far and fail. That problem I will save for later!

I then removed the Mint SSD and put the Win 7 SSD disk back in and tried to boot. I was shocked to see an error message from grub saying the disk was missing! When I ran grub rescue for the Mint SSD I had left a storage drive in the machine and I think grub got installed/recovered to that and not the Mint SSD as intended. Disabling the storage HDD in the bios I tried booting into Win 7 again and now I get an error saying `Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key` The Win 7 SSD shows up in the bios and is selected as the boot device. I think grub (that got installed on the wrong (storage) drive), must have screwed up the win 7 boot loader now. How can I fix/reverse this? Why is the win 7 drive not booting?

Comment: Do you have MBR or GPT partitions structures?

Answer (score 0):

to repair only windows bootloader  i suggest to unplug other disk and you may boot from windows install disk and use in console:

repair mbr:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force /mbr
```

then find windows instalations dirs:

```
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: This didn't work. Before I did this, I ran gparted and set the flag to boot for this drive. Now I'm getting `BOOTMGR missing` error. Have tried all usual steps to fix that.

Comment: did bootrec find your windows instalation dir?

Comment: you may try: `bootrec /RebuildBcd` then `bootrec /fixMbr` then `bootrec /fixboot`

Comment: bootrec doesn't seem to find my win installation. I get something like: "windows installations 0". The win 7 dvd does find it though so it is there. Just can't boot it. So this did not work.